# vb.net DB connection string for multiple systems

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am making a vb project with sql server which is already provided within vb with same as express editions's interface.

I want to make a project where i want to allow user to add|update|delete|search through DB!
the main problem is as per the project the most important functionality required is i want to publish my project (that i know hw to publish) but problem is in different pc path will differ of the DB.

How can i use App.config and other things so that my desktop app  automatically detects the new path of the app?

please guide me with an example.

I have tried 'n' no. of things but it only works in select statement, but when i insert any data it shows me no error but the database @ back doesn't changes..!

My question must have been a repeated one! Pardon me for it as i was unable to get solution from almost all i have seen on this site!

In app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SQLConnStr"
       connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\balancesheet.mdf;Integra‌​ted Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

in form page:

```
Dim ConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString()
Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
```

select statement works...insert doesn't even in the same system.

Comment: Why do you have so many exclamation marks in your question?

Comment: sorry..:P
bcoz m xclaimed that i have wasted 2 days in this thing...(no xclamination)..:(

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: in app.config
      <connectionStrings>

        <add name="SQLConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\balancesheet.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    
</connectionStrings>

in form page
 Dim ConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString()
        Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

select statement works...insert doesn't
even in te same system..

Answer (score 0):

You should have the .exe files and the database in the same folder. This way, the path could be set like:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Therefore, it will not look up for user paths such as c:\Users\etc\etc

The connection string can be encrypted in the app.config file as well. You could also reference it to a dedicated database server where you store all the data for all the users.
The connection string for this in the app.config file would be:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

For your case though I believe SQL Server Compact Edition is a better option. You should create your database in the Debug or Release folders within your project. Set the database reference to that and exclude any relative paths as such, so it should be only "yourdatabase.sdf" If you plan to send out the project, then include in the folder only the .exe file and the .sdf file. Watch this video for more help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLWi-McMVWA

Comment: ok awesome exlanation...thanx mate..!!
but u have mentioned Database=dbname;
what is dbname here??...in my case my SQLSERVER DB name is if "balancesheet" then what shall i write? and even in connection string u mentioned Database=myDatabase(with no .mdf)?
sorry for stupid question..

Comment: and myv db is already in the .exe consisting folder i.e "bin\debug\"

Comment: m getting dis error even on select statement after editing app.config

"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file balancesheet.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Comment: @AmItPagarIa I edited my answer. Don't forget to set the status of the question as answered.

Comment: i will surely go through this video....
m damn sure it will help..
if it really then i will surely tick mark it...:)